# jQuery looping command

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this animation repeat continuously from the beginning?
http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1, dir = 1, curFx = 'fadeIn';
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (i == 2 && $('#slide1').is(':visible')) {
        $('#slide1').fadeOut(6000);             
        return;
    }

    $('#slide'+ i)[curFx](1500);

    i = i + 1*dir;

    if (i == 10 || i == -1) {
        dir = (dir == 1)?-1:1;
        curFx = (curFx == 'fadeIn')?'fadeOut':'fadeIn';
    }        
}, 1500);
});
```

Comment: The code you posted here is different than the code in your fiddle.

Comment: @FelixKling and now the OP **Completely** changed his question...

Comment: sorry you got points taken off, people can be jerks. You are doing it wrong. I'll post an example in a minute

Comment: @Shanimal The question deserved downvoting. It has nothing to do with being "jerks" and everything to do with indicating that this isn't how you ask a question on SO.

Comment: Anthony Grist, tell me how to ask a question correctly? I am not a programmer and trying to get some help.

Comment: @Phillip. Use Ryan's answer.

Comment: @Anthony, I looked at the edit, his question seemed ok to me. So we all can be better informed, what was the problem?

Comment: @Phillip I'd seriously advise you to use http://www.jslint.com/ for all future JavaScript code that you write. For three reasons: one, you will have less bugs, two, the code will be easier for people to read and understand, and three, you will gain good habits. I use JSLint before I put any JavaScript anywhere. The code in my answer validates with four errors, three of which are perfectly fine, the fourth can be corrected easily by adding `"use strict";` in-between the first and second line.

Comment: One of these questions is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528109/jquery-looping-animation-from-the-beginning?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Use asynchronous recursion.

```
$(document).ready(function me() {
    $("#slide1").fadeIn(100).delay(100).fadeOut(100, function () {
        (function startFade(slide, step) {
            if ((slide === 1) && (step === -1)) {
                setTimeout(me, 100);
            } else if (slide < 10) {
                $("#slide" + slide)[step === 1 ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"](100, function () {
                    startFade(slide + step, step);
                });
            } else {
                startFade(slide - step, -step);
            }
        }(2, 1));
    });
});
```

Comment: Ryan's code suggestion is based on this here: http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/11/

Comment: Does this answer your question? If not let me know why and I will try to change it to solve the problem.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion here http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/q9EZg/5/. The only problem is that the animation will repeat from slide2 and not from slide1. I tried to repositioning the code but no luck.

Comment: Ok give me a sec to get my head around it, been answering other questions so I keep losing the context of conversations lol.

Comment: How's that (see my answer above - just edited it)? I think that's what you're looking for. If not I think it should be fairly simple to get doing what you need from there.

Comment: Sorry I think I got confused by the fact that you had called them slides (I thought you wanted them to fade in and out). Check my answer now, does that do what you wanted?

Comment: Here's a little bit simpler recursion, which also uses fade. change functions from "fadeIn" and "fadeOut" to "show" and "hide" respectively http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/41/

Comment: @Shanimal that is what I thought he was trying to do at first, but when you look at his fiddles that isn't right (see one of my edits).

Comment: @Phillip I have edited the code again to do what your latest fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/8/) does.

Comment: Fade slides in and out http://jsfiddle.net/ryansmith94/cBB8d/

Comment: @Ryan, np, I liked your answer because it said "recursion." I had already solved it and it was on my cliboard and I figured instead of competing with your answer I'd just post my similar solution here in the notes. fwiw I thought you were too obliging. Phillip had been given more than enough to resolve this issue on his own. Good job none-the-less

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that rolls back to the start.

```
function loopback(){
...
   //inside your innermost fn:
   loopback();  
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a little shorter version:

```
function animate(slide){
     slide.fadeIn(500, function() {
        var next = slide.next();
         if(next.length > 0){
              animate(next);
         }
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    animate($('#slide1'));
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/6/

Comment: This is not recursive, see update for recursivity: http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/12/

Comment: namkha87 suggestion was based on this: http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/11/