# jQuery looping animation from the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like this animation to repeat from the very beginning each time (#slide1).

I tried the setTimeout method but could not get it to work.
I am using a simple line by line since the timing difference and (lack of knowledge).
Thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9EZg/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slide1").fadeIn(2000, function () {
$("#slide1").delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
$("#slide2").delay(6000).fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide3").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide4").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide5").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide6").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide7").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide8").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#slide9").fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("div").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function () {});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});

<div id="slide1">Slide 1</div>
<div id="slide2">Slide 2</div>
<div id="slide3">Slide 3</div>
<div id="slide4">Slide 4</div>
<div id="slide5">Slide 5</div>
<div id="slide6">Slide 6</div>
<div id="slide7">Slide 7</div>
<div id="slide8">Slide 8</div>
<div id="slide9">Slide 9</div>
<div id="slide10">Slide 10</div>
```

Comment: Your code runs fine... but in your JSFiddle you didn't include the jQuery library.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you asking the question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526185/jquery-looping-command)? This is the same question as the previous one before some edits. Why did you even edit your previous question if this is the one you actually wanted to ask? People were upset after you changed your question completely and you could have avoided that.

Comment: You realize if you name those functions you can stack them instead of nesting them into the void of torturous souls like you're doing now.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I agree with you that this can be cleaned up. I would recommend creating a generic function and pass in an array of slides names (selectors)

Comment: Horrible indention. Makes it harder to read.

Comment: I did not format it horribly, it just got that way when I saved it.
I have reformatted.

Comment: Felix, sorry about that. Can you help loop my animation?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526185/jquery-looping-command/14526292#14526292   
See the edits to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9EZg/4/)...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function animate() {
        $("#slide1").fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $("#slide1").delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
            $("#slide2").delay(6000).fadeIn(1000, function () {
                $("#slide3").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                    $("#slide4").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                        $("#slide5").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                            $("#slide6").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                $("#slide7").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                    $("#slide8").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                        $("#slide9").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                            $("div").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, animate); // Call animate again
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    }()); // Call the animate function
});
```

I wrapped your code in a Animate function that is called again after the last step.

PS. And yes you forget to enable JQuery in JSFiddle, but I assume that is not your question or related to your question.

Comment: Hi Bart, the animation is making the slide 1 to animate strangely.

Comment: @Phillip I just took your animation and repeated it. Maybe you need to have a proper setup and tear down section to make sure it starts/finishes in the right state.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you main animation logic in a function (which you have already done). Like this:

```
function Animate() {
   //your animation logic
}
```

And then call the same function at regular interval. Like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   Animate()
}, 1000);
```

But, you definitely need to improve your main logic and structure.

Comment: Downside of this option is that you need to set the setInterval duration to the exact value. If you add or remove a slide it breaks. Why not call the animation after it finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(intervalTest, 1000);
});

function intervalTest() {
    $("#slide1").fadeIn(2000, function () {
        $("#slide1").delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
        $("#slide2").delay(6000).fadeIn(1000, function () {
            $("#slide3").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                $("#slide4").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                    $("#slide5").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                        $("#slide6").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                            $("#slide7").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                $("#slide8").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                    $("#slide9").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                        $("div").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function () {});
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice way of queueing up animations,  you can make an animation queue array containing objects with instructions, something like this:

```
var animationQueueArr = [
    {
        selector: '#slide1',
        delay: 4000,
        animation: 'fadeIn',
        duration: 2000,
        callback: true
    },
    {
        selector: '#slide1',
        animation: 'fadeOut',
        duration: 2000,
        callback: false
    },
    {
        selector: '#slide2',
        delay: 6000,
        animation: 'fadeIn',
        duration: 2000,
        callback: true
    }
    // and so on
];
```

Then, you can loop over them:

```
function animate (i, skipDelayBool) {
    skipDelayBool = skipDelayBool || false;
    var animationObj = animationQueueArr[i];
    if (animationObj.delay && false === skipDelayBool) {
        return setTimeout(function () {
            animate(i, true);
        }, animationObj.delay);
    }
    if (false === animationObj.callback) {
        $(animationObj.selector)[animationObj.animation](animationObj.duration);
        i += 1;
        i %= animationQueueArr.length;  // reset back to 0 if necessary to start new loop
        animate(i);
    } else {
        $(animationObj.selector)[animationObj.animation](animationObj.duration,
        function () {
            i += 1;
            i %= animationQueueArr.length;
            animate(i);
        );
    }
}


animate(0);
```

Note I havent tested this, but it will send you on the right path and away from your worst indentation nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered this question once. Duplicate: [jQuery looping command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526185/jquery-looping-command/14526292#14526292)
See the edits to the question and you will see that I have answered it twice now.

```
$(document).ready(function me() {
    $("#slide1").fadeIn(100).delay(100).fadeOut(100, function () {
        (function startFade(slide, step) {
            if ((slide === 1) && (step === -1)) {
                setTimeout(me, 100);
            } else if (slide < 10) {
                $("#slide" + slide)[step === 1 ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"](100, function () {
                    startFade(slide + step, step);
                });
            } else {
                startFade(slide - step, -step);
            }
        }(2, 1));
    });
});
```